# String split function with hql

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have following hql query,

```
from Channe where ip='1.11.6.0';
```

But in the db the IP is saving as  `1.11.6.0:8080` .

So I need to modify the query in a way that, split the ip with a delimiter ':' and take the firstcome value. I do not wish to modify the search with value `1.11.6.0:8080`.

Comment: Have you tried the Like query.Please try "from Channe where ip LIKE'10.131.56.40%';

Comment: Why did you un-accept the answer? Is it not working for you? If not, why not?

Answer (score 2):

See this page in the Hibernate docs. On the page below there is a section called **14.10. Expressions**

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

It says, among other things:

> string concatenation ...||... or concat(...,...) current_date(),
>
> ...
>
> Any function or operator defined by EJB-QL 3.0: substring(), trim(), lower(), upper(),
>   length(), locate(), abs(), sqrt(), bit_length(), mod()

But you are actually better off doing as @Hansraj suggests in the comments and appending a wildcard to your search term

```
String query = "from Channe where ip like :term";

entityManager.createQuery(query).setParameter("term",ipString + "%");
```

This assumes that your data type is string, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SPLIT(".", FIELDNAME)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Say variable ip had the address

```
ip = "10.131.56.40:8080";
var ipSplit = ip.Split(':');
var ipStart = ipSplit[0];
```

ipStart will store only 10.131.56.40

This could solve your problem